# Adding infowindow to cartodb map using api

Tags: carto, layers, carto-js, infowindow

I think this should be easy, but I just can't work it out.  I am building a multi-layer map using cartodb (own opensource server).
Layers display well. but I have two problems.
1) the layer select drop down box is not displaying
2) I can't get infowindows to on lphoto layer.

I have a template at the top and have tried adding

```
photos.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
```

But this just creates an error.
Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- based on 
https://gist.github.com/jsanz/94e802930460ba850f8f
https://github.com/Vizzuality/CartoDB-Tutorials/blob/master/cartodb-js/adding_infowindows.md
-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
          html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
          }
        </style>


 <script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
    <div class="cartodb-popup">
      <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
       <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
         <div class="cartodb-popup-header">
           <img style="width: 100%" src="http://cartodb.com/assets/logos/logos_full_cartodb_light-

5ef5e4ff558f4f8d178ab2c8faa231c1.png"></src>
         </div>
         <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
           <!-- content.data contains the field info -->
           <h4>City: </h4>
           <h2>{{content.data.name}}</h2>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
    </div>
  </script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cartodb-

libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodbui/assets/2.15.2/stylesheets/embeds.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="http://cartodb-

libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodbui/assets/2.15.2/javascripts/cdb.js"></script>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {

          //Create the leaflet map
          var map = L.map('map', {
              zoomControl: true,
              center: [-33.64661,151.1252963],
          layer_selector:true,
          cartodb_logo:false,
              zoom: 12
          });

          var basemap = L.tileLayer

('http://sixmaps.wildwalks.com/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Base_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', 

{
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 

contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
          }).addTo(map);

          // Promise for the first layer
          var tracks = cartodb.createLayer(map, {
        user_name:'wildwalks', 

tiler_protocol:'http',tiler_domain:'mad.tl',tiler_port:'8181',sql_api_protocol:'http',sql_api_domain:

'mad.tl',sql_api_endpoint:'/api/v1/sql',sql_api_port:8080,cdn_url:null,no_cdn:true,type: 'cartoDB',
            sublayers: [
            {
              sql: 'SELECT * FROM ww_walk_component',
              cartocss: '#layer{line-color: #FF0000; line-width: 5; line-opacity: 0.7;}'
            }
            ]
          });

          // Promise for the second layer
          var photos = cartodb.createLayer(map, {
                user_name:'wildwalks', 

tiler_protocol:'http',tiler_domain:'mad.tl',tiler_port:'8181',sql_api_protocol:'http',sql_api_domain:

'mad.tl',sql_api_endpoint:'/api/v1/sql',sql_api_port:8080,cdn_url:null,no_cdn:true,type: 'cartoDB',
            sublayers: [
            {
              sql: 'SELECT * FROM ww_images_gplus',
              cartocss: '#images{  marker-placement: point;marker-type: ellipse;marker-width: 10; 

marker-fill: #0000ff; marker-opacity:0.5;}',
          interactivity: 'cartodb_id',
            }
            ]



          });



          // When both are done, add them to the map;
          $.when(tracks,photos).done(function(ltracks,lphotos){
            ltracks.addTo(map);
            lphotos.addTo(map);
          });




        });
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified a little bit the structure of your code in order to improve legibility and functionality. As mentioned at the begining of the html, I have used [a block](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/3950e1a9b458a9177f9c) from a colleague that has all the elements (infowindows, tooltips, legend, fixed boxes...) added to a `createLayer` CartoDB.js map.

Fist, have a look at the end of the block and observe how I added the two layers to the map. You used two variables, but I have used a kind of "sandwich" methodology. Then you can get the sublayer you want to interact with, using the `getSubLayer` method. Finally, in order to add an infowindows you should get as parameters the map object, the layer and the fields used in the infowindows template.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- based on 
http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/3950e1a9b458a9177f9c
-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Your Title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

   <script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
      <div class="cartodb-popup">
        <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
         <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
           <div class="cartodb-popup-header"></div>
           <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
             <!-- content.data contains the field info -->
             <h3>Id: </h3>
             <h4>{{content.data.cartodb_id}}</h4>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
      </div>
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodbui/assets/2.15.2/stylesheets/embeds.css" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="http://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodbui/assets/2.15.2/javascripts/cdb.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      //Create the leaflet map
      var map = L.map('map', {
        zoomControl: true,
        center: [-33.64661,151.1252963],
        layer_selector:true,
        cartodb_logo:false,
        zoom: 12
      });
      L.tileLayer('http://sixmaps.wildwalks.com/arcgis/rest/services/public/NSW_Base_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
      }).addTo(map);
      cartodb.createLayer(map, {
        user_name:'wildwalks', 
        tiler_protocol:'http',
        tiler_domain:'mad.tl',
        tiler_port:'8181',
        sql_api_protocol:'http',
        sql_api_domain:'mad.tl',
        sql_api_endpoint:'/api/v1/sql',
        sql_api_port:8080,
        cdn_url:null,
        no_cdn:true,
        type: 'cartoDB',
        sublayers: [
          {
            sql: 'SELECT * FROM ww_walk_component',
            cartocss: '#layer{line-color: #FF0000; line-width: 5; line-opacity: 0.7;}'
          },
        {
          sql: 'SELECT * FROM ww_images_gplus',
          cartocss: '#images{  marker-placement: point;marker-type: ellipse;marker-width: 10; marker-fill: #0000ff; marker-opacity:0.5;}',
          interactivity: 'cartodb_id',
        }]
      })
      .addTo(map)
      // When both are done, add them to the map;
      .done(function(layer){
        photos = layer.getSubLayer(1);
        cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(
          map, photos, ['cartodb_id'],
          {
             infowindowTemplate: $('#infowindow_template').html()
          });
      });
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Note: you should customize your title, the infowindows template and this last interaction.